# How to create array of pairs with all combination in n1ql Couchbase

Tags: couchbase

I have a nested array of objects in a Couchbase document:

```
doc1:{

arr:[v1, v2, v3, v4]// v1, v2, v3 are objects

}
```

Expected result

```
arr[
{v1, v2}, 
{v1, v3}, 
{v1, v4},
{v2, v3},
{v2, v4},
{v3, v4}
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean that arr should be an array of arrays, this should do it:

```
    JsonDocument doc = bucket.get(docId);
    JsonArray arr = doc.content().getArray("arr");
    JsonArray out = JsonArray.create();

    for(int i = 0; i < arr.size() - 1; i ++) {
        for(int j = i; j < arr.size(); j ++) {
            JsonArray subArray = JsonArray.create()
                    .add(out.get(i))
                    .add(out.get(j));
            out.add(subArray);
        }
    }

    doc.content().put("arr", out);
    bucket.replace(doc);
```

Answer (score 1):

Expected output is changed to reflect valid JSON. i.e {"one":v1,"two":v2}

```
SELECT  ARRAY_FLATTEN((ARRAY (ARRAY {"one":v1, "two":v2} FOR v2 IN d.arr[pos+1:] WHEN  v2 IS VALUED END) FOR pos:v1 IN d.arr END),2)
FROM default AS d ;

SELECT RAW ARRAY_FLATTEN((ARRAY (ARRAY {"one":v1, "two":v2} FOR v2 IN arr[pos+1:] WHEN  v2 IS VALUED END) FOR pos:v1 IN arr END),2)
LET arr = [{"x":"a1"},{"x":"a2"},{"x":"a3"},{"x":"a4"}];

SELECT ARRAY_FLATTEN((ARRAY (ARRAY [v1, v2] FOR v2 IN arr[pos+1:] WHEN  v2 IS VALUED END) FOR pos:v1 IN arr END),1) AS b
LET arr = ["one","two","three","four"];
```